# ubuntu username not set during installation

Tags: system-installation

I installed an ubuntu server and somehow happend to skip the user accounts and time setup process. 
Now the system loads up and asks username and password which I have none. 
Is there a way to access the account setup facility or is there any default username and password for ubuntu? 
Id thought of root and guest account but they're not active yet.

Comment: Can you add what Ubuntu server version you installed? Do you have physical access to the server or is the machine remote?

Comment: User `ubuntu` pass "blank"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open recovery mode and chroot to the ubuntu installation. Then, try to add an user with `useradd` or set root password with `passwd`.